# SVG - Follow rotated path

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation, snap.svg

I'm trying to have a circle follow an elliptical path that is rotated, using Snap.svg, but I've ran into a problem.

Using the getPointAtLength only returns the point of the path that is not rotated, so when I rotate the path, the circle will still follow the original path, before rotation.

```
var firstOrbit = s.path("M250,400a150,75 0 1,0 300,0a150,75 0 1,0 -300,0")
.attr({stroke: "#000", strokeWidth:"5", fill: "transparent"});
var len = firstOrbit.getTotalLength();
firstOrbit = firstOrbit.transform('r75,400,400');
var circleA = s.circle(0,0,10);
var startingPointA = Snap.path.getPointAtLength(firstOrbit, 0);
Snap.animate(0, len, function(value){
    var movePoint = firstOrbit.getPointAtLength(value);
    circleA.attr({ cx: movePoint.x, cy: movePoint.y });
}, 2000, mina.linear);
```

The problem is, that the ellipse rotates, but the path that circleA follows does not, so it follows a wrong path. Is there an easy way to fix this, or do I have to calculate the difference at each step of the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two possible solutions for this issue. Either you will have to put the `<path>` and `<circle>` inside a `<g>` group and apply transformations to the group Or find actual point on path and then find the transformed point by applying the transformation matrix.

**Solution 1**

```
var len = firstOrbit.getTotalLength();
var circleA = s.circle(0,0,10);

var group = s.g(firstOrbit,circleA);
group = group.transform('r75,400,400');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZc8j/62/)

**Solution 2**

```
var pt = s.node.createSVGPoint();
Snap.animate(0, len, function(value){
    var movePoint = firstOrbit.getPointAtLength(value);
    pt.x = movePoint.x; 
    pt.y = movePoint.y;
    movePoint = pt.matrixTransform(firstOrbit.node.getCTM());   
    circleA.attr({ cx: movePoint.x, cy: movePoint.y });
}, 2000, mina.linear);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZc8j/61/)

Answer (score 1):

Put both the circle and the path inside a group.  Apply the transform/rotation to the group (instead of the path) so that both the circle and the path inherit the same transform.
.