# Translate point along the path that has been translated and scaled

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, transform, scale

I have gone through the 'point-along-path' d3 visualization through this code: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868. I understood the code.

And used it in my code and works successfully for moving the circle along the path between two locations on the map. The problem arises on translating the path to the new position and scale it. There circle still moving in its old path, not the transformed path.

The original path is shown in the console as:

```
<path fill="#f4ab03" d="M938.9205757035511,198.71688021141057A210.4627512788538,210.4627512788538 0 0,1 1071.4577386252327,362.2053205383533"></path>
```

The transformed path is showing as:

```
<path fill="#f4ab03" d="M938.9205757035511,198.71688021141057A210.4627512788538,210.4627512788538 0 0,1 1071.4577386252327,362.2053205383533" transform="translate(-128.89999389648438,-54.400001525878906)scale(1.2000000476837158,1.2000000476837158)"></path>
```

Only transformed and scaled are extra in the transformed path. I have searched and tried too much on that but unable to solve that issue. I have tried as:

```
function translateAlong(path, translateMap, scaleMap) {
                var l = path.getTotalLength();
                    return function(d, i, a) {
                        return function(t) {
                            if (translateMap) {
                                // here still taken as old path values, not wanted
                                return "translate(" + (p.x + translateMap[0]) + "," + ( p.y + translateMap[1]) + ") scale(" + scaleMap + "," + scaleMap + ")";
                            } else {
                                return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
                            }
                            //return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
                    };
                };
            }
```

Hopefully, I expressed my question clear enough.

Thanks

Comment: You'll find solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27697757/5768908

Comment: Thanks Gerardo, it worked